# Line passage and centering in CSS

Tags: css

I would like to get this result in CSS

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByKse.png)

I have for now this:

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE6Zf.png)

I don't understand how I can center the elements and pass a line in CSS?

I wanted to use a `margin: auto`, but I think that's not a good practice?

Here is the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/ep2zy85g/).

Thanks

Comment: Where have you got that it's a bad practice to use margin auto, i'm curious? Here you have an quick example of how to achive this with your [code](https://jsfiddle.net/ot842sjp/13/). One tip is that to structure up your elements in more blocks to get more seperation of concern later on in your styling, you should notice that in my givn example. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @Blazorman: Thank you your code is perfect ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the elements in div

```
  <div class="text-container">
    <span class="user">User : Toto </span>
    <span class="last-connection">Votre dernière connexion : 09/12/2021 à 12:41:34</span>
  </div>
```

and add this style for parent

```
.text-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```